# Nikon D3200 battery drain out quickly

Tags: battery, image-stabilization, adapter, nikon-d3200

My Nikon 3200 battery drains out quickly. When the company says 500 to 600 photos in a complete charge, I am getting only 70 to 100 photos(without flash and manual focusing) in a full charge. Is it due to the VR mode? Any idea about similar issues?

Comment: You say you are focusing manually. Are you using Live View to focus manually?

Comment: Nope. most of the time I use viewfinder.

Comment: About charging, My adapter's charging status indicator does not stay lit up on full charge as mentioned in the user manual. Instead it starts blinking at a higher frequency after about an hour. But, when inserting the battery in dslr it shows full charge.

Comment: Is the battery Nikon branded? Have you tried another battery in the camera? Under normal conditions, even in the cold you should not be able to drain a healthy battery that fast. Suspect the battery.

Comment: I never used my cam below or above the 20 to 35 degree Celsius. Also I am using a brand new adapter and battery that Nikon ships with the DSLR. I purchased it from Amazon 3 months back.

Comment: What do you mean by adapter? A battery grip? Or part of the charger?

Comment: The battery charger.
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003ZYF3MI/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_3/175-8433617-6817661?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_r=1YRG9159DPMWAEB5EGX0&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_p=1944687622&pf_rd_i=B0083Z21O2

Comment: Does the memory card access light on the back of the camera blink a lot, even when you haven't just taken a picture?

Comment: No. It flashes only when taking a video/photo and for a few seconds when turning on the camera.

Comment: Is the battery new? Did it always do this, or did it just start happening?

Comment: The battery is new and it was always like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the charger is not indicating a full charge by displaying a constant light but blinks at a higher frequency after about an hour then the battery appears to not yet be fully charged. If you are only going by the four or five segment battery symbol on your camera's LCD anything over about 75% will usually show fully charged, since the first bar doesn't disappear until you're down to about 75%. If you leave the battery in the charger for several hours does the blinking eventually stop?

One thing I have noticed with "smart" (chipped) lithium ion type batteries is that when you charge them for the first few times after they have been on the shelf for an extended period they need to be charged and exhausted several times before they can be charged to full capacity. Leave the battery on the charger for several hours, then use it until it is down to between 10-15% and charge it for several hours again. repeat this cycle three or four times. This should help to condition the battery to accept a full charge.

If the battery has been left in the charger several hours, used until low, then charged again for a number of cycles and is still displaying the same behavior then one of three things is happening (listed in order of likelihood):

- The battery is defective and can't hold its rated capacity
- The charger is defective and isn't fully charging the battery to its rated capacity
- The camera is defective and is excessively draining the battery

If the charger and battery were included with the camera when new three months ago, then this is a warranty issue and you should pursue it with the appropriate Nikon Service Center for where the camera was purchased.

If you bought the charger and battery separately it is quite likely you were sold a counterfeit. There are probably more fake Canon and Nikon camera batteries in the marketplace than genuine ones. If you didn't buy them from an authorised Canon dealer you almost certainly purchased a fake.

Comment: If I leave the battery in the charger for several hours, the led will stop blinking(off state). What does that mean?

Comment: Does it stay steady for a few minutes before going off?

Comment: I didn't noticed that yet. But, if unplugged and start charging later without using the battery, it will start charging like the battery is drained out.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few reasons why your battery life is bad:

Cold temperatures or other extreme exposure
Old battery with lots of charge cycles
Battery is damaged physically
Battery has been shorted or charged too quickly

I would recommend that you research batteries before you buy and make sure they are either from Nikon or a trusted source. The other simple thing to do is just make sure you have the right batteries and a decent charger. Do some research and buy good batteries as well as a new charger, they might last longer. Amazon is the best place to start.

If none of these things help, contact Nikon directly and see if it could be a problem with the camera.

Comment: I never used my cam below or above the 20 to 35 degree Celsius.  Also I am using a brand new adapter and battery that Nikon ships with the DSLR. I purchased it from Amazon 3 months back.

Comment: @AbhijithSJ Contact Nikon and see if they can get you a replacement.